# Grails can no longer save record to Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

I made some changes to my packages, basically created a new project, everything works fine except when I try to save my changes I get this message:

```
Message: Unsupported feature
    Line | Method
->>  125 | throwSqlException                   in oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    162 | throwSqlException                   in     ''
|    227 | throwSqlException . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    537 | throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException in     ''
|   3091 | prepareStatement . . . . . . . . .  in oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection
|    140 | $tt__save                           in gov.mt.mdt.step.ReportController
|    200 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                            in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter                            in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                                 in java.lang.Thread
```

Here is the database info from DataSource.config:

```
development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:DEV"
            driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            username = "step"
            password = "****"
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        }
    }

    production {
       dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:DEV"
            driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            username = "step"
            password = "****"
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
            }

        }
```

Same result in development and production.  I do have ojdbc14.jar in the lib folder.  It worked fine before, I did insert a record directly into the database, but that did not have cause an issue previously.  I can read and edit records no problem.

One thing I thought could be an issue is changelog.groovy...

Comment: Did you try to clean project ?>

Comment: your oracle version please. did you try obdc6.jar?

Comment: Try clean and refresh dependencies to your project

Comment: My Oracle version is 11g.  I tried a clean and refresh dependencies.  Will try odbc6.jar

Comment: Ojdbc6 did the trick!